# how to config PyCharm so it will show only functions that i wrote in "call hierarchy" (and not internal python functions)?

Tags: pycharm, call, hierarchy, call-graph, call-hierarchy

In PyCharm, there is a feature called `call hierarchy` (under **Navigate** -> **call hierarchy**) which shows the function call graph.
the graph contains too much information.
I want to filter it only by the functions I wrote, not internal python functions. how should I do this? I dint find thee option.

Answer (score 1):

I'm using PyCharm 2023.1
Opening the call hierarchy with scope of "All" shows EVERYTHING.
If you configure a new scope (from within the call hierarchy window), you can include the folders you want, but most importantly, you exclude recursively the "External Dependencies". I've been able to get a clean call list this way.